# node-soap - How to pass certificates and basic Authorization header with every request?

Tags: node.js, ssl, soap, basic-authentication, node-soap

I am using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) lib for SOAP services and using it for first time. I am having requirement that I need to pass both Certificates and Basic Authorization header with every request compulsory.

I have implemented my code as follow :

```
var options = {
    wsdl_options: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./xxx.key")),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./xxx.crt")),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./xxx.pem")),
    },
    wsdl_headers : {    
     Authorization : 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username +':'+ password ).toString('base64')
    },
    "overrideRootElement": {
        "namespace": "con",
    },
    envelopeKey : 'soapenv'
};



soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {
    if(err){
        console.log("Error ::: >",err);
        res.json({message : err});
    }


    if(client){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(client.describe()));
        var data = actualRequestObject  

        client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(
            fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./XXX.key")), 
            fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./XXX.crt")),
            fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./XXX.pem"))
        ));

        client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity(username, password));
        client.IndicativeEnrichment(data, function(err, result){
            console.log("lastRequest :::: >>>>> ",client.lastRequest);
            if(err){
                console.log("ERROR Enrichment :::: >>> ", err);
            }

            if(result){
                console.log("RESULT ::: >>>>", result);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

When I am trying to set Basic auth and Certs both using setSecurity() method. It overrides the first thing that I've set using setSecurity(). I am getting unauthorized error if I don't pass any one of these.

Please help me with providing the solution the solution.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by overriding request module. `request : request.defaults({
      headers : {
       Authorization : 'Basic  XXXXXXXXX'
      }
     })` But I'm not sure if it is right approach or not. If any one have an idea about it please help me.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to get both client certificates and basic authentication would be to [implement your own `node-soap` security protocol](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#security). You can either get inspired by the [existing `node-soap` security protocols](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/tree/master/lib/security) and combine them, or write one which is generic enough to chain two (or more) existing security protocols. It would of course be even better to create a pull request with the solution, so it can be considered for inclusion directly in `node-soap`.

Personally ended up passing additional `options` with a [configured `https.Agent(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_agent) to the   [`BasicAuthSecurity`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#basicauthsecurity) constructor/[class](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/lib/security/BasicAuthSecurity.js).

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  // https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_agent
  agent: new https.Agent({
    key: someKeyBuffer,
    cert: someCertBuffer,
    ca: [
      someCACertBuffer,
    ]
  });
}

client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity('username', 'password', options));
```

This way can also be used to combine basic authentication with [`.pfx` or `.p12`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) files used in [`ClientSSLSecurityPFX`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/lib/security/ClientSSLSecurityPFX.js)

Comment: Thank you @Joel for your suggestion. I'll surely try this.